# now.getMilliseconds();

Tags: seconds

Here is a set of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 

<html xmlns="www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">


<title>Lots of Time</title>
<body>
<h1>Times</h1>
<script "type/javascript">
now = new Date();
localtime = now.toString();
utctime = now.toGMTString();
hours = now.getHours();
mins = now.getMinutes();
secs = now.getSeconds();
milli = now.getMilliseconds();
document.write("<h2>Local time:</h2> " + localtime + "<br/>");
document.write("<h2>UTC time</h2> " + utctime);
document.write("<h1>");
document.write(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs + ":" milli);
document.write("</h1>");
document.write("<h1>");
document.write(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs + ":" milli);
document.write("</h1>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything worked fine until I added the line with the getMilliseconds();

Any help would be much appreciated.
Sincerely,
Erin

Comment: `<script "type/javascript">`? `document.write`? No problem description? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: You need a "+" before the variable name "milli"

Comment: you can close the question

Answer (score 1):

Add a plus sign so it looks like:

```
document.write(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs + ":" + milli);
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
document.write(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs + ":" milli);
```

to

```
document.write(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs + ":" + milli);
```